# Autorun ElasticSearch with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elastic

All of the tutorials online say to manually start elasticsearch as a daemon with a docker command from the command line. Is there a way to auto run it like redis, postgres and other services do from the docker compose yaml file?

Comment: I found a script in bin/docker-start.sh that I added some code to. I am still experimenting with it.

Comment: you can easily use the example from https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/ to run the elasticsearch using docker compose

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

This is an official docker-compose for running Elasticsearch, and will make a good starting point for whatever you're trying to achieve. This would be the key part:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${TAG}
    environment: ['http.host=0.0.0.0', 'transport.host=127.0.0.1', 'ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}']
    ports: ['127.0.0.1:9200:9200']
    networks: ['stack']
```

But I'd recommend cloning the entire repository locally and running `docker-compose up` to experiment.